# Vulkan compute shader with 16-bit floating point operation on Android device

Tags: floating-point, glsl, vulkan

Is there any way to use 16-bit floating point in Vulkan compute shader?

I have a matrix multiplication compute shader with a single buffer for matrix A,B, and C. On the host side, I use http://half.sourceforge.net/ to convert float32 to float16.

```
half* matrixTmp;
vkMapMemory(device, bufferMemory, 0, matrixSize, 0, (void **) &matrixTmp));
int offset = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < M*K; i++) {
    matrixTmp[offset+i] = half_cast<half>(matrixA[i]); 
}
offset = (M*K);
for(int i = 0; i < K*N; i++) {
    matrixTmp[offset+i] = half_cast<half>(matrixB[i]); 
}
```

For float32, I use the following compute shader layout.

```
layout(binding = 0) buffer matrixBuffer {
    vec4 matrixABC[];
};
```

How to use the buffer in compute shader if it contains 16-bit floating point?

**Edit:**
I use Vulkan for Android device and I also need my shader to be able to do 16-bit operation, not storage only.

Answer (score 2):

Support for this was added by the VK_KHR_16bit_storage extension, which was promoted to core in Vulkan 1.1. You need to check/enable the `VkPhysicalDevice16BitStorageFeaturesKHR::storageBuffer16BitAccess` feature.

Then you can use `float16_t`, `f16vec2`, etc. types in your buffer declaration in GLSL. These come from the pre-Vulkan [GL_AMD_gpu_shader_half_float](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/AMD/AMD_gpu_shader_half_float.txt) extension. You can look at the glslang compiler's [float16 test](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glslang/blob/master/Test/spv.float16.frag) for examples.

Comment: So, the extension is available for AMD only? Is there any way to use it on android? I forgot to mention that I use Vulkan on android.

Comment: @TsesarRizqi: Vulkan uses SPIR-V, not GLSL, remember? So it's the SPIR-V specification (and the compiler that builds it) that matters, not the name on the extension. And SPIR-V already supports variable precision floats and integers. If the Glslang compiler supports the "AMD_gpu_shader_half_float" extension, then you have access to it using that compiler.

Comment: @NicolBolas I will try.

Answer (score 2):

For the buffer storage side of things there is [VK_KHR_16bit_storage](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/1.0/doc/specs/vulkan/appendices/VK_KHR_16bit_storage.txt)[(SPV_KHR_16bit_storage](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/KhronosGroup/SPIRV-Registry/blob/master/extensions/KHR/SPV_KHR_16bit_storage.html)). This adds support for 16 bit floats to e.g. ssbos.

If you want to explicitly work with half floats in the shader (calculation), these are available through [VK_AMD_gpu_shader_half_float](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/1.0/doc/specs/vulkan/appendices/VK_AMD_gpu_shader_half_float.txt), so right now for AMD only.

Once enabled, you can use 16 bit data types:

```
#extension GL_AMD_gpu_shader_half_float : enable

struct Particle
{
    f16vec2 pos;
    f16vec2 vel;
    f16vec4 gradientPos;
    float16_t age;
};
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am running Vulkan on android. Is there any option for android?

Comment: Not with explicit types like for the AMD extensions, but there are packing and unpacking functions for glsl that may be what you're looking for: ```packHalf2x16```and ```unpackHalf2x16```. So if you pack two 16 bit floats on the host side you can use the unpack funciton in the shader to extract those, though that won't give you lower precision calculations.

Comment: Which gives better performance, using `vec4[length/2]` with `packHalf2x16` and `unpackHalf2x16` or using `vec4[length]`?